# Display HTML on EditText from a JSON String

Tags: java, android, html, json, android-edittext

I'm trying to display some basic HTML to an EditText on android.

I already found out that the way to do it is using the Html.fromHtml(String source) method.
And this in fact works just fine.

However my string source is being extracted from a JSONObject and for some reason it ignores the HTML tags inside it.

I use these lines to change the text on the corresponding EditText:

```
text = JSONdata.getJSONObject("text");
clip.setText(Html.fromHtml("text.getString("content")));
```

However this just displays the String without any format. **Anyone here knows why is this happening?**

What drives me even crazier is that if I try this:

```
clip.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Heading</h2>" + text.getString("content")));
```

That will display the word heading with the proper format while still ignoring the tags found on the following string.

I guess I need to change the JSONString to another type of data but I haven't found anything useful yet.

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give the string returned from this
text.getString("content")

Comment: if the original string has <h2>Heading</h2> it will return: &lt;h2&gt;Heading&lt;/h2&gt; So JSON is escaping the <> symbols.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you surround the string with tags?

```
clip.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html>"+text.getString("content")+"</html>));
```

Comment: Well it doesn't display the <html></html> tags so I assume they are getting interpreted correctly however the content string keeps appearing without any format.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to edit the html tags, do not use Html.fromhtml

EditTeht displays correctly does not all tags. 
Its work:

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

Comment: I can't quite understand your answer.
However if I don't use Html.fromHtml the text is just displayed verbatim without any format whatsoever.

Comment: OK, I read it wrong the first time.
So, try to use the decode /enсode making json-file. You should see something in the tags: `<a href=\"http:\/\/reporterr.org\"><strong>Details<\/strong><\/a>`